# Why is this not returning None if blank array?

Tags: python, arrays

So, Im trying to print the largest number in the array alongside its index so example [1,4] but I am trying to return none when the array is blank. But nothing is being outputted to the screen.

```
def Largest(Array):
    Array = []
    if Array == []:
        return None
    largest = 0
    for x in range(0, len(Array)):
        if(Array[x] > largest):
            largest = A[x]
        index = Array.index(Array[x])
        B = [largest, index]
    return (B)
```

When I run the function Largest(Array) in the terminal, nothing is printed.

Comment: This code defines but does not call the function

Comment: If you're calling the function, are you printing what it returns? `print(Largest([...]))`

Comment: As written, that function will _always_ return `None`. Re: "But nothing is being outputted to the screen.", there are no calls to `print` in your code, so I wouldn't expect anything to be printed. If you're calling `Largest` from an interactive interpreter, remember that nothing will be printed when an expression evaluates to `None`.

Comment: Why do you have the variable `Array`? Shouldn't you be using the parameter `array` instead?

Comment: Get out of the habit of doing `for index in range(len(array)):` Use `for item in array:`

Comment: Ah yeah sorry made some edits. I meant Array and not array

Comment: Why are you reassigning the parameter variable? How will you process the actual parameter?

Comment: This is what we have been instructed to do. To call the function as Largest(Array) hence why I have reassigned the parameter variable.

Comment: You must have misunderstood. When you do `Array = []` inside the function, it replaces the argument that was supplied by the caller with an empty list.

Comment: You were probably told to do that *outside* the function, e.g. `Array = []` followed by `Largest(Array))`

Comment: BTW, these are lists, not arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Interactive Python REPLs don't print the return value of a function when it returns `None`, because that's what functions that don't return anything return by default.

So if you want to see the return value in cases like this, you need to call `print()` explicitly.

```
print(Largest([]))
```